# How to control an Installed Program on Windows with python

Tags: python, automation, audacity

I'm fairly new to Python, and am still in the process of learning it.  I just want to know if the following is possible, and if anyone could give me a few pointers on where to start.

I have ~6,000 audio files that need to be processed - reduce noise, normalize, and finally, compress - to reduce the size without losing quality.  I want to do this through [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org), which has these actions under the "Effects" menu.  I was wondering if I could use Python to automate the work for the ~6000 files, or if a better alternative exists (maybe through Windows command prompt?).

Any kind of information to help steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should start with reading manual about [audacity scripting](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html).